# php remove all spaces UNLESS condition

Tags: php, string, text, echo, str-replace

Title is pretty much self explanatory...

I want to remove all spaces unless it's inside `" "` or `''`

for example :

```
<?php

$myText = <<<EOF

   echo 'Those spaces should not be removed';    echo 'but the spaces between the semicolon TO the next echo should be removed';

EOF;

$string = str_replace(' ', '', $myText); //this remove everything :(

?>
```

I'm expecting the $string would be :

```
echo'Those spaces should not be removed';echo'but the spaces between the semicolon TO the next echo should be removed';
```

Thanks !

Comment: Don't decorate every question with "Any Idea?". Ideas are what **you** are supposed to present based on prior research. -- Regex, or `php -w`.

Comment: @Michael Laffargue I just want to compress any php script so no unused spaces in the code...

Comment: Use [`php_strip_whitespace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-strip-whitespace.php).

Comment: A simple way could just be to loop through the whole string, checking if you are inside quotes or double quotes. And if you are, don't remove any spaces, otherwise remove a space if found.

Comment: PHP VERSION 6 DEVELOPERS PLEASE DEVELOP THIS (OR SIMILAR) :: str_replace( ' ', '', $myText, {UNLESS this condition} );

Very helpful!!!

Comment: `<<<EOF` - obviously you are aware of heredoc notation. This should make you think: do you really want to remove all spaces that are not within quotes? Also, what about escaped quotes? Or nested quotes? If you want to serve your PHP script compressed, why not as PHAR archive?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Break up $string into an array of separated $string_parts

while (preg_match('/\'\;[^\']+\'/', $string)) {
preg_match('/\'\;[^\']+\'/', $string, $pattern);
$string_explode = explode($pattern[0], $string);
$string_parts[] = $string_explode[0];
$string_parts[] = $pattern[0];
$string = $string_explode[1];
}


// Add last remaining part of original $string to $string_parts array

$string_parts[] = $string_explode[1];


// Collapse the spaces in every second element in $string_parts array

$count_string_parts = count($string_parts);
for ($i = 1; $i < $count_string_parts; $i = $i + 2) {
$string_parts[$i] = str_replace(' ', '', $string_parts[$i]);
}


// Put $string back together again from $string_parts array

$string = implode($string_parts);
```